# Make table cells zoomable when zooming in browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to format a table inside a fieldset, both are inside a form. here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
fieldset{width:90%;}
table {width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
table,td {border:1px solid black;}
td.abc {width:40%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Text Text</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Text </td>
            <td class="abc"> 
                <input size='25' type="text"/>
                <select>
                    <option>Text text text</option>
                    <option> Text </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Text text
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Text </td>
            <td class="abc"> 
                <input size='25' type="text"/>
                <select>
                    <option>Text text text</option>
                    <option> Text </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Text text
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how could I make a text input and a select stay on the same row when I zoom in browser (by pressing ctr and + keys).Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget table, use DIV. That the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to use div and my problem was solved :) You remind me about the purpose of table: it's not used for designing, it's used for displaying data :) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with Sandeep - I've always had trouble with tables and instead have gone to @HTMLhelpers with  tags and css for formatting.  I have no problems with zooming in, a nice feature for older folks, visually impaired, etc.

Here is a contact page snippet similar to what you want to do with a fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    *@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    *@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    *@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

</fieldset>
```